# Выбор слов из базы SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server, sqlite

Каким должен быть запрос SQL?

У меня есть русский словарь более 165.000 слов в mysql. Мне необходимо выбрать только те слова в которых есть буквы (т, e, в, и, р, п) при этом исключить любые другие слова в которых нет переданной буквы. Программа должна выдать слово Привет, тир, пир и любые другие которые можно собрать из переданного набора букв. В некоторых случаях одной буквы может быть > 1

Чтобы было понятнее объясню задачу. Программе нужно передать набор букв и в ответ получить слова которые можно собрать исключительно из этого набора букв.

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: WHERE word LIKE '%т%' OR word LIKE '%е%' и тд типо такого

Comment: @pwnz Разве не AND вместо OR?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE word NOT REGEXP '[^тевирп]';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e10c9eda563e469d92c8be57658229a)